# MSBuild and .CsProjects

Tags: msbuild

I am using MSbuild for CI tool and have many C# projects located in different directories. There many dependents projects  as well. Some developers use Add Project option to add project and some directly connect to .dll file and i have no control over it. some cases all projects added to a solution So if i compile that solution then it takes care of all dependencies. But i do not this in my auto build. I want to compile all .csproj and output .dlls to a particular folder and then all projects including web should point to this folder for reference.

Want to know if this a ideal process?

Answer (score 0):

**In my Project we do the same and it works**. Sometimes we have project references and sometimes we have direct dlls references in a folder called "Solution DLLs".

**How we do it**:
The reason is that we have many projects (120 or more) and we have split them in several solutions. One of the solutions is for framework and commmon dlls. These Dlls are copied in postbuild scripts to a "Solutions Dlls" folder and checked in in TFS. Later our build scripts copy these solutions dlls...

**How it works**:
It works "fine" and is acceptable. But many problems came (and sometimes still come) with postbuild scripts not working fine. We are aiming to reduce the number of csprojs to  50-60 and use again one single solution.